# PHP "Contact" form, e-mail address safe from spam?

Tags: php, forms, email, spam

So I got this PHP code for a "Contact us" form online (I do not code PHP myself), but it contains my e-mail address in full. Does the following form make my e-mail safe from spammers?

contact.php file (real email has been replaced by MYEMAIL@COMPANY.COM):

```
<?php
// Contact Form 

// Get posted data into local variables
$EmailFrom = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['EmailFrom'])); 
$EmailTo = "MYEMAIL@COMPANY.COM";
$Subject = "A User Has Contacted You";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// Validation
$validationOK=true;
if (Trim($EmailFrom)=="") $validationOK=false;
if (Trim($Name)=="") $validationOK=false;
if (Trim($Message)=="") $validationOK=false;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// Prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// Send E-Mail 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// Redirect to Success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=success.htm\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

html snippet:

```
<form method="POST" action="contact.php">

...

</form>
```

I've read that e-mail addresses contained in PHP is completely safe from crawlers since it is all server side (that is assuming your server/site is secure). Not sure if this is true or not, there's so much information out there I couldn't find a definitive answer after searching online. If someone could confirm if this code is safe to use or not that would be great, thanks!

Comment: It's true - as long as your server is correctly configured to execute PHP, your address is safe. That doesn't mean that spammers can't just fill out your form to spam you though -they will, and that's life with a contact form unless you put in hoops to jump through like filling in arithmetic problems, captchas or increasingly non-user-friendly stuff.

Comment: Looks like whoever wrote it doesn't write much PHP code themselves too :P

Comment: Alex, that comment makes me sad, thinking that I chose the wrong form template :( lol...

Comment: Michael, is it likely the robots will still send spam if the fields (Name, Email--xxxx@xxxx.xxx format required, and Message) are all required/need validation? I'm fully prepared for the human spam haha. I'll probably integrate a captcha in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they have access to that file and read it, you're fine. They can't get at it. It's all server side like you said.

Answer (score 1):

The address is safe, except in the unlikely event that the files gets served as plain text and is readable (as Sean says), but you should read up on [email injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823914/whats-current-best-practice-to-prevent-email-injection-attacks-in-php) as you're vulnerable to those.

Answer (score 1):

Your e-mail is protected since it's all serverside, unless for example he has fpt access to your website or you have some type of vulnerability.

Also you might want to consider something like this to prevent flooding.

```
    session_start()

    define('TIME_INTERVAL', 120);

    if(isset($_SESSION['ip']) && (time() - $_SESSION['last_post']) < TIME_INTERVAL) 
    }
       die('stop spamming !');
    {

    $_SESSION['last_post'] = time();
    $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Also regarding your e-mail validation you might wanna take a look at this, which also validates the domain of the email to see if it's an existing email server.

```
function validate_mail($email)
{
 if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
 {
    list($username,$domain)=split('@',$email);
    if(checkdnsrr($domain,'MX')) 
    {
      return true;
    } 
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks this looks great, I'm assuming both go into the contact.php file, but not sure where. Does anywhere work? Looks like I need to start getting more familiar with javascript/PHP.. I can KIND OF understand the code :)

Comment: yep add them in your contact.php and use like $validationOK = validate_mail($email); // it will either assign true or false;

Comment: and about the flood script add it on top of your php file before executing anything.

Comment: also regarding the = split('@',$email) you might wanna try it with explode instead cause it might pop some error.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, You are safe.  Because the PHP elements will only be processed on the server, therefore there is no way for anyone to see your email address.