# PHP form mail to work with invisible form field to filter bots

Tags: php, html, webforms

I read this post: [What is a good invisible captcha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972507/what-is-a-good-invisible-captcha) about using a hidden field in a web form to stop basic bots from pelting your website with spam mail via  your web sites form mail. I'm currently using a php script to process my form mail. I built the script by following a 'bullet proff web form' tutorial I found. It looks like this:

```
<?php
// Pick up the form data and assign it to variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

// Build the email (replace the address in the $to section with your own)
$to = 'hello@cipherbunny.com';
$subject = "New message: $topic";
$message = "$name said: $comments";
$headers = "From: $email";

// Data cleaning function
  function clean_data($string) {
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $string = stripslashes($string);
  }
  $string = strip_tags($string);
  return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
}

// Mail header removal
function remove_headers($string) { 
  $headers = array(
    "/to\:/i",
    "/from\:/i",
    "/bcc\:/i",
    "/cc\:/i",
    "/Content\-Transfer\-Encoding\:/i",
    "/Content\-Type\:/i",
    "/Mime\-Version\:/i" 
  ); 
  $string = preg_replace($headers, '', $string);
  return strip_tags($string);
} 

// Pick up the cleaned form data
$name = remove_headers($_POST['name']);
$email = remove_headers($_POST['email']);
$topic = remove_headers($_POST['topic']);
$comments = remove_headers($_POST['comments']);

// Send the mail using PHPs mail() function
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Redirect
header("Location: http://foobar/success.html");
```

I'd like to modify this script so that if a hidden field with the identifier 'other_email' was filled in then the form email wouldn't get sent. I'm guess it's as straight forward as wrapping the above code in an if statement to check if the field is complete. I've tried adding this under the "//Pick up the form data and assign it to variables" code:

```
$testBot = $_POST['other_email'];
```

then writing:

```
if(other_email == "") //If other_email form section is blank then... 
{
    run all the code above inserted here;
}
else
{
 Don't know what I should put here to stop it posting, yet still show the success form so 
 the spam bot don't know 

}
```

any help much appreciated. I have to say I don't really have a lot of php knowledge, I'm just starting to learn about it and thought form mail would be a good start.

How do I make this work in PhP?

Comment: Try [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) instead of implementing your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(other_email == "") //If other_email form section is blank then... 
{
    run all the code above inserted here;
}
else
{
 header("Location: http://foobar/success.html");

}
```

keeping it very simple, it will work for you..

actually, it will

- not submit / mail you anything...so NO SPAM
- a simple bot will take it as it did it...

if you can use php on success page, then set a session variable (to make bot think it did its job, something like `email_sent=true` or `success=true`) and use that variable in success page, you will do it in `else case` where bot submitted the form..

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean send message with fields?
Try this:

```
<?php
// Pick up the form data and assign it to variables
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$topic = $_REQUEST['topic'];
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];

// Build the email (replace the address in the $to section with your own)
if($name !== null && $email !== null && $topic !== null && $comments !== null){
$to = 'hello@cipherbunny.com';
$subject = "New message: $topic";
$message = "$name said: $comments";
$headers = "From: $email";

// Data cleaning function
  function clean_data($string) {
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $string = stripslashes($string);
  }
  $string = strip_tags($string);
  return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
}

// Mail header removal
function remove_headers($string) { 
  $headers = array(
    "/to\:/i",
    "/from\:/i",
    "/bcc\:/i",
    "/cc\:/i",
    "/Content\-Transfer\-Encoding\:/i",
    "/Content\-Type\:/i",
    "/Mime\-Version\:/i" 
  ); 
  $string = preg_replace($headers, '', $string);
  return strip_tags($string);
} 

// Pick up the cleaned form data
$name = remove_headers($_POST['name']);
$email = remove_headers($_POST['email']);
$topic = remove_headers($_POST['topic']);
$comments = remove_headers($_POST['comments']);

// Send the mail using PHPs mail() function
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Redirect
header("Location: http://foobar/success.html"); 
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis" />
<title>Send</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#" method="POST">
Name     : <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Email    : <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Topic    : <input type="text" name="topic" /><br />
Comments : <textarea name="comments"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```