# Validate whether its a human submitting a form and not a DOS :-0

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How do you ensure that whoever is submitting a form is doing it and its not some DOS attack?

I was hoping there was an easy way to generate some kind of image or squiggle that the user has to enter prior to submitting a web form

Technology Stack
MVC with C#

Comment: These are called CAPTCHAs; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450835/how-do-you-stop-scripters-from-slamming-your-website-hundreds-of-times-a-second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capcha

Try using Capcha possibly?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean that you want to check that it's not a bot (rather than DOS which is something else). For that, take a look at [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://forum.coolwebawards.com/threads/7-Captcha-in-C-.NET) is a short tutorial on generating a capcha.  a [search on google](http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+captcha) reveals many more.